# Is it OK to push .env to private repository;

Tags: gitlab, environment-variables, gitlab-ci

I'm working on **private Nodejs** project on Gitlab. As I know, it is **not good** to push .env (or other type of environment variables) file to remote repository. Currently I want to do CI/CD using Gitlab-CI and .gitlab-ci.yml file allows people to list all environment variables into this file, and we must **push this file** to gitlab repository. So, is there a confict here? If yes, how do we do CI/CD with environment variables using gitlab-ci?
Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Are they environment variables intended for your production environment? Then go ahead and put them into the repository (unless they contain stuff like credentials, in which case that might be iffy).

Are they environment variables for your development machine? If so, you might still want to put them into a repository (e. g. as a template for other devs) but somewhere inside a /util directory, where your software doesn't actually consume them.

Also, the environment variables inside the .gitlab-ci.yml are used during the build, not during the program's runtime, so no, there shouldn't be a clash (unless your CI pipieline actually starts your software to run integration tests or something).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you said **unless they contain stuff like credentials, in which case that might be iffy** => So gitlab-ci is useless in production? If not, how can I use gitlab to deploy automatically my Nodejs module in production? Additionally, what you mean in **the environment variables inside the .gitlab-ci.yml are used during the build, not during the program's runtime**